# ControlTemplate - pre defined content

Tags: wpf

Is it possible to create a ControlTemplate for example for a Grid which would make that every Grid using this template will have stackpanel, canvas etc. as a content?

Comment: Grid is a *Panel*. You cannot provide a *ControlTemplate* for a *Panel*. What do you want to do?

Comment: well I am having custom library control called LayoutDocumentControl and I want to have every LayoutDocumentControl with stackpanel, scrollviewer and canvas inside of it as default

Comment: @fex Try putting your default template in the `<UserControl.Template>` of your `LayoutDocumentControl`, and be sure to include a `<ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />` where you want to position the content for your `UserControl`